# How do I edit Wikipedia's top right infobox?

Tags: wikipedia

I'm currently trying to edit the infobox for [iTunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes) on Wikipedia.

I know how to edit every other section of the page, and know that there is a main "Edit this page" link near the top of the page as well.  But how do you edit the content in the top-right box that list some of the summary of the page?

(for example, there is a "Stable Release" in that box but I can't find that text no matter which section I edit or even if I do an "edit this page")

Screenshot:

[image]

I want to edit the page in another language where the stable version still says 11.1.5:

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the infobox starting with the app icon and a picture of the app underneath that?

Comment: yes, screenshot will be added in next minute

Answer (score 1):

That's called the [infobox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aInfobox).  To edit that box, hit the main edit link at the top of the page.  On the iTunes page, you'll see a section of code that starts like so:

```
{{Infobox software
| name               = iTunes
| logo               = [[File:ITunes 11 Logo.png|64px]]
| screenshot         = [[File:Itunes 11.png|300px]]
| caption            = iTunes 11 running on [[OS X Mountain Lion]]
```

In general, you can search for `{{Infobox`.

Updating this will update that box.

The software template includes other templates to retrieve, for example, the version number. I'd imagine so the same bit of information can be used in multiple places but maintained once.  The iTunes version number is stored at [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template%3aLatest_stable_software_release/iTunes&action=edit).  That behavior is governed by the `frequently updated` tag on the infobox, as described in [the software infobox documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aInfobox_Software).

For better or for worse, this version data seems to be language specific.  So if, for example, you were updating Chinese Wikipedia, the appropriate link would be [here](https://zh.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template%3aLatest_stable_software_release/iTunes&action=edit), which is the same but at `zh.wikipedia` instead of `en.wikipedia`.  The easier way to get there is to click on the `[±]` sign next to the version information.

Comment: for example, stable release is 11.2 but I can't find 11.2 any where in the edit box?  -- I am doing the edit for another language)

Comment: please see updated question for how 11.1.5 still shows up in another language

Comment: Updated.  Looks like the version info is stored per language.  I guess that's useful for software that is translated into different languages but not always at the same time?

Comment: just out of curiosity, how do you know the page is in Chinese?

Comment: @動靜能量 `zh` is the [ISO 639-1 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) for Chinese.

Comment: Indeed!  Or in Chinese, http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1%E4%BB%A3%E7%A0%81%E8%A1%A8 :-).

Comment: Ooh, that does not copy/paste well.

Comment: no i mean from looking at my screenshot in the OP, how do you know it is in Chinese?

Comment: The technical term for what I did is a "Wild Ass Guess".  I looked at the list of other languages available for the ITunes page, clicked on one of them with similar looking characters, and saw if it showed the problem and resembled your screenshot.  It did, therefore I concluded that was the page you were referring to.  But yes, it would have been easier I suppose if you had supplied that link, instead of supplying the `en` link and having me look for the `zh` link.